# How to debug this code for linked list?

Tags: c

I wrote this to perform push and reverse operation on linked list but the push/reverse function is not working somehow. I don't know where the problem is, everything seems to be fine. Can someone help me out? I think there's a problem with the head of the linked list or the parameter of the functions. Do I need to declare a pointer to pointer as parameter?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node NODE;
NODE *head1 = NULL;
int flag = 1;
int choice;

void push(NODE*);
void menu();
void reverse(NODE*);
void display(NODE*);

int main() {
    do {
        menu();
        if (choice == 1) {
            push(head1);
            display(head1);
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            reverse(head1);
            display(head1);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } while (1);


}

void push(NODE *head) { //function to create the linked list
    int choice1, flag = 1;
    do {
        NODE *new_node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
        puts("Enter new node data:");
        scanf("%d", &new_node->data);
        if (!head) {
            head = new_node;
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
        }
        puts("Do you want to continue? Press 1:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &choice1);
        if (choice1 != 1) {
            flag = 0;
        }
    } while (flag);
}

void menu() {
    puts("Enter 1 to push, 2 to reverse, anything else to exit:");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
}

void reverse(NODE *head) { //function to reverse it
    NODE *prev = NULL, *next = NULL;
    NODE *current = head;
    while (current) {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}

void display(NODE *head) {
    NODE *temp = head;
    puts("Status of the linked list:");
    for (; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        printf("%d=> ", temp->data);
    }
    puts("NULL");
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, actual result/output or misbehaviour and much more information about what makes you think that it does not work.

Comment: I want to create the linked list as a stack. @BadMiscuit

Comment: Also please decide which language you believe to be using. At a guess, I'd say C. What C++ related information is in the question or expected by you in an answer?

Comment: There is nothing special about pointers. Assigning to a parameter works the same regardless of the parameter's type.

Comment: What parameter should I use in the functions push, reverse and display? Do I have to use a pointer to pointer parameter?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Well, I solved it. See the answer below you'll learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code. I'll start with a small snippet.

```
/* global */
NODE *head1 = NULL;

/* in main */
push(head1);

void push(NODE *head) { //function to create the linked list
    int choice1, flag = 1;
    do {
        NODE *new_node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
        puts("Enter new node data:");
        scanf("%d", &new_node->data);
        if (!head) {
            head = new_node;
            head->next = NULL;
    }
```

`push()` is taking a pointer to NODE, allocating something and then assigning it to that pointer. **this only modifies the local copy of the pointer in push()** , leaving `head1` unmodified. To modify `head1`, you either need to return a pointer or take a pointer to pointer.

That is either

```
void push(NODE** head)
```

or

```
NODE* push(NODE* head)

head1 = push(head1);
```

Also you are allocating `sizeof(NODE*)`, the size of a pointer (typically 8 or 4 bytes). This should be `sizeof(NODE)`.

Comment: The same applies to `reverse(NODE** head)`. `display` is OK as it does not modify the list.